# Tensor Products with Broadcasting

Tags: matrix, theano

Suppose we have a matrix `A` with size `m x n` and a tensor `B` with size `k x s x n x t`. I would like to multiply this tensor and matrix together. When I am running the command `theano.tensor.dot(A,B)`, the shape of output would be `m x k x s x t` which means that Theano is broadcasting the 2D matrix in a wrong way.

I would like to output to have the size `k x s x m x t` meaning that only the last two dimensions of tensor gets multiplied by the matrix. How can I fix this broadcasting issue?